# How to fix "1 error potentially fixable with the `--fix` option" when using vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, eslint

When compiling my vue.js (v 3.10.0) project, I get a error which says "1 error potentially fixable with the `--fix` option." because of eslint.

I have already searched for some solutions, that said I had to change some config-files but I couldn't find any of the described files. I also tried to use `npm run lint -- --fix` and it worked, but I do not want to execute this line of code every time.

Is there any way to do this, so for example like to "disable" eslint?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can run this command right before `vue-cli-service build`. Just modify your `package.json` `"scripts"` section.
`package.json`:

```
...
"build": "npm run lint -- --fix && vue-cli-service build",
...
```

### ES Lint removing:

Just drop these lines of code into your `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module.rules.delete('eslint');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works, but is there another way to solve this which does not change my code? If not, I will continue using this.

Comment: @Fanbneyl, if you want something to change, you have to change some code :)

Comment: Just saw your the eslint removing part, it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Fanbneyl, I mean you can disable ES Lint just for one line of code, just putting the comment above `// eslint-disable-line`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I think I saw that while looking for a solution, but I do not want to use it in any line so your answer fixes my problem perfectly.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the package.json code. It would be: "build": "npm run lint  --fix && vue-cli-service build", right?

Comment: @Gregorio, No this is not a mistake, it is by design. It is needed to separate the params passed to npm command itself and params passed to your script. [Reference](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5518).

Answer (score 1):

**It was fixed with this command**

npm run lint -- --fix

If you want to disable (prettier/prettier) use this code. In the .eslintrc.json file

```
rules: { 
'prettier/prettier': 'off' 
}
```

Comment: If you are using prettier then just off with above command, after then run `npm run lint -- --fix`